# How to set Focus to a DatePicker Field

Tags: javascript, struts2

My jsp Page :

```
<table style="width: 100%" >
                    <tr>
                    <td class="lable" align="right"><s:text  name="label.learningLicenceNo" />:</td>
                    <td><s:textfield name="learningLicenceNo" id="learningLicenceNo"/>
                    <td class="lable" align="right"><s:text name="label.dateofBirth" />:</td >
                    <td ><sx:datetimepicker name="llDateOfBirth" id="llDateOfBirth" displayFormat="dd-MM-yyyy" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td align="right" class="lable"><s:text name="label.issuedByState" />:</td>
                    <td><s:select
                            list="#{'1':'Andhra Pradesh', '2':'Madhya Pradesh'}" 
                            name="llFromState" 
                            headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select" id="llFromState"/></td>
                    <td class="lable" align="right"><s:text name="label.rtoOffice" />:</td>
                    <td><s:select
                                list="#{'1':'khairatabad', '2':'Madhya Pradesh'}" 
                                name="llFromRTO" 
                                headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select" id="llFromRTO" />
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <div>
                <s:reset cssClass="button" key="button.clearAll" align="right" />
                <s:submit cssClass="button" name="" key="button.submit" onclick="return validateNewLL()"/>
                <s:submit cssClass="button" name="" key="button.close" method="close"/>
            </div>
```

JavaScript :

```
function
{
  var llDateOfBirth=document.getElementById("dlDateOfBirth");
  if(llDateOfBirth == "")
  {
      alert("Enter Date Of Birth");
      llDateOfBirth.focus();
      return false;
   }
 }
```

Everythig is fine but focus was not set to the Date-picker  field .

I have searched goggle a lot

Can we set focus by using java Script

Thank you

Comment: Your datePicker field Id is 'llDateOfBirth'.

Comment: Post the rendered html for the input field generated by datepicker. BTW Struts2 dojo tags are deprecated along with plugin.

Comment: give the generated html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [API](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/datetimepicker.html) has an onfocus field -

Or do you require it only if the field isnt set

Comment: When i click on the submit button ,If the Date field is not entered it has to show an alert box and when i click on ok in alert box the focus has to be set to the datepicker field . I got alert box but the focus was not set to the datepicker field . I am using <sx:datetimepicker> tag . and struts2 version is 2.3.15

Answer (score 0):

Try avoid using `DOJO tags` they are deprecated. Instead of them use  the `Struts 2 jquery tags` 
In your code after alert statement. 
try adding this one

```
$('#llDateOfBirth').focus();
```

instead of

```
llDateOfBirth.focus();
```